# Crystal report sub report has not table exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset, subreport

This may be a common question, but I wasn't able to find a solution after googling. I am using Crystal Report with C# to do reporting. I'm having some problems with sub reports:
I want to create a Monthly report for Order and OrderDetail. I did it as per the following code, but when run, it throws the Exception "Report has no table" on the sub-report. Can you help me?

```
RpOrder rpt = new RpOrder();
RpOrderDetail sub = new RpOrderDetail();
DataSet dsOrder = new dsOrder();            
DataSet dsOrderDetail = new dsOrderDetail();
dsOrder.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
dsOrder.Tables.Add(new DataTable());
dsOrderDetail.Tables.Add(new DataTable());

foreach(Order nx in listNX )
{
    dsOrder.Tables[0].Rows.Add(
        new object[]{nx.NgayOrder,nx.GetIsNhapString(),nx.NguoiGiaoHang,nx.TongTien}
    );
    foreach(OrderDetail ct in nx.ChiTiets)
    {
        dsOrder.Tables[1].Rows.Add(new object []{
            ct.HangHoa.TenHangHoa,
            ct.HangHoa.MaHang,
            ct.DonGia,
            ct.SoLuong,
            ct.SoLuong * ct.DonGia
        });
    }
}           
rpt.SetDataSource(dsOrder.Tables[0]);
rpt.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(dsOrder.Tables[1]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
rpt.SetDataSource(dsOrder);
```

?

If the line above doesn't work check the records in the tables and try to turn the order, set subreport first.

Comment: I tried both, but there are no change. Wish more help

Comment: Sorry , I cannot help. rpt.SetDataSource(dsOrder);  should be able to resolve the issue if the order of the returned tables is the same as the order of the report/subreports.

Comment: You have RpOrderDetail sub = new RpOrderDetail(); but uou are not using it are you trying to add the subreport in runtime ?

Comment: Oh, I think it's just a code-mistake, the RpOrderDetail object is useless, I must delete it before

Comment: What is the error when you use rpt.SetDataSource(dsOrder); ?

Comment: Still be "report has no table", the same when rpt.SetDataSource(dsOrder.Tables[0]);

Answer (score 0):

If the sub report was added to the main report before changes were made then go to the main report, right click on the sub report and "Re-import Subreport"